# How to create an index with conditionals and use it

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with only three columns: `id`, `time`, `value`

I already have an index on `(id, time)`.

Now I need to speed up for a recent data query, so I think I need to create a new index for every day.

```
create index heat_20181001_20181003 on mytable using
brin ("id", "time") where time between '2018-10-01 00:00:00' and 
'2018-10-03 23:59:59';
```

But when I query, It shows use old index, and the new one is not used.

Query:

```
EXPLAIN  ANALYZE ( select * from mytable where time between 
'2018-10-01 00:00:00' and '2018-10-03 23:59:59' and "id" = '453615414');
```

Result:

```
Index Scan using "mytable_id_579df36b7ac8aa8e_idx" on mytable 
  (cost=0.57..3931.98 rows=1133 width=87) (actual time=3.045..12294.511 rows=3762 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((("id")::text = '453615414'::text) AND ("time" >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00+08'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("time" <= '2018-10-03 23:59:59+08'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning time: 0.320 ms
Execution time: 12295.688 ms
(4 rows)
```

How can I use the index for the query? Or how can I improve it?

Comment: Looks like you want partitioning tables.  Check here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

If the time interval is variable, your original index is perfect (that's why PostgreSQL is using it).

If the time interval is constant, the perfect index would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable (id)
   WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-03 23:59:59';
```

The BRIN index is probably useless because the physical order of the tuples in the table is not identical to the index order.

You should certainly *not* create an index per day, your original index is good enough.

Comment: When I create this index, then I want to drop it, but when I do "drop index  index_name;     It show XXXXX does not exist  , but I check \di+,  is exist.

Comment: What exactly is the name?

Comment: iot_mytable_id_idx and  iot_mytable_id_idx1

Comment: Maybe a typo. Or an extra space at the end? Did you try `psql`'s autocompletion feature?

Comment: it's weird, autocompletion is no iot_mytable_id_idx and iot_mytable_id_idx1, is possible I have index with  (id, time) then I create index CREATE INDEX ON mytable (id)
   WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-03 23:59:59'; then it extend on my older index???

Comment: Aha, I see. It is probably in a schema that in not on your `search_path`. Try qualifying it with the schema.

Comment: but how? the type is index, how can I drop it without use "  drop index  "?

Comment: I find the anwser.....the index name is     "iot_mytable_id_idx1" , it use quotation marks,  thanks a lot Laurenz